# Ignore values on insert with ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Insert Statement like:

```
f"INSERT INTO `system_measurements`(`Global_irradiance_tilted_in_Wh_per_m2`, `a_id`, `subDate`) VALUES ('{temp}', '{temp_id}', '{i.date()}')"
```

And want it to ignore existing entries without checking the date everytime. So i thouhgt I could use

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a_id=a_id
```

But it still adds all values to the table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE system_measurements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question as saying that a new row is inserted despite the `on duplicate key`.

In order for `on duplicate key` to work, you need a unique constraint or index.  The `update` takes place when the query violates the `unique` constraint.

I am guessing that you want this on `a_id`, so be use you have something like:

```
alter table system_measurements add constraint unq_ system_measurements_a_id
    unique (a_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE` will do nothing other than discovering that it is a duplicate.  "Duplicate" is checked via the `PRIMARY KEY` and any `UNIQUE` keys.

Simply stick `IGNORE` after `INSERT` in the SQL you have.

Comment: I read about INSERT IGNORE that it's not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: But do any of the caveats in that other Q&A apply here?